# github api returning 1 at the end of json. is this a mistake?

Tags: php, json, github-api

using curl http://github.com/api/v2/json/user/show/username
github's user api returns this:

```
...,"login":"myUsername","email":"myEmail@test.com"}}**1**
```

why is there a 1 after the json? Is that a mistake on their part, or is that supposed to be used for something?

```
<?php

function getGithub($url="user/show/username") {
    $github = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($github, CURLOPT_URL, "http://github.com/api/v2/json/". $url); 
    return curl_exec($github);
}
```

trying to

```
echo getGithub();
```

but since there's the 1 on the end, I have to

```
echo rtrim(getGithub(), "1");
```

Comment: I don't see it when I visit the URL in my browser or use wget.

Comment: no.good.at.coding's right, visit the URL you just posted, and then search your code for extra output, for example echoing something that evaluates to `true`.

Comment: I added the php that I was using to grab the json. Do you happen to see what I might be doing wrong that appends the 1 to the json?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`.  curl_exec() is currently returning true, which you're then echoing, which gets printed as 1.