# Send mp3 file with php to telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I use this Api for manage robot .

https://github.com/mgp25/Telegram-Bot-API

I want send MP3 from URL to telegram user so i change class like this and add this line after line 399

```
'audio/mpeg'   =>  '.mp3',
```

mp3 send with success but my problem is function return json and not convert json to array;I echo returned data and I've got it at the end of json string add one 1 like this

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":46328,"from":{"id":115910361,"first_name":"Persian Robot","username":"TPersian_bot"},"chat":{"id":133180682,"first_name":"Mohammad Reza","last_name":"Behzadfar","username":"Lifesoul","type":"private"},"date":1457607231,"audio":{"duration":176,"mime_type":"audio\/mpeg","title":"Mozoo Chiye","performer":"Yasin","file_id":"BQADBAADKwAD2aboBniCRUQ1WE48Ag","file_size":7137408}}}1
```

and this my code:

```
    $Telegram = new Telegram(API);
$result = $Telegram->sendAudio(133180682, "https://rjmediamusic.com/media/mp3/Yasin-Mozoo-Chiye.mp3");
var_dump(json_decode(rtrim($result,'1'),TRUE));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About **1** in the end of json, there is plenty of question-answers on stackoverflow ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821595/github-api-returning-1-at-the-end-of-json-is-this-a-mistake)). But if you will not change anything and still want to get an array, you can try this

```
$json = '{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":46328,"from":{"id":115910361,"first_name":"Persian Robot","username":"TPersian_bot"},"chat":{"id":133180682,"first_name":"Mohammad Reza","last_name":"Behzadfar","username":"Lifesoul","type":"private"},"date":1457607231,"audio":{"duration":176,"mime_type":"audio\/mpeg","title":"Mozoo Chiye","performer":"Yasin","file_id":"BQADBAADKwAD2aboBniCRUQ1WE48Ag","file_size":7137408}}}1';
var_dump(json_decode(trim($json, '1')));
```

Comment: thanks for answer but still json_decode not work and return some like this `{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":46710,"from":{"id":115910361,"first_name":"Persian Robot","username":"TPersian_bot"},"chat":{"id":133180682,"first_name":"Mohammad Reza","last_name":"Behzadfar","username":"Lifesoul","type":"private"},"date":1457616116,"audio":{"duration":176,"mime_type":"audio\/mpeg","title":"Mozoo Chiye","performer":"Yasin","file_id":"BQADBAADMAAD2aboBo8Mz9M11OZ-Ag","file_size":7137408}}}NULL`

Comment: For your string in question it is.http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e93875f1147b2b5aea6f20e37451983f1cd3520